# What handle bars are these

Tags: bmx

I have handlebars with "PZ & company" stamped on them and I can't find any thing on them

[image]

Comment: What do you need to know about these bars. Do you have some problem to solve or are you just interested who made them? Most BMX bikes posted here are completely generic and not notable in any way. I wonder why the number of BMX bikes to be identified is so disproportionately highh.

Answer (score 2):

The company name is Pazzaz and the logo for the company is a circle with "PZ & Company"  The company name was started about 1996.

Here is a [picture of a product](https://damianbikes.gr/product/pazzaz-bmx-seat-clamp-black/) sold by Pazzaz with the logo

[image]

Here is a quote from an interview with a representative of Pazzaz from October of 1999

> You may not know it, but you have probably used Pazzaz made parts before.
> The company, Wei Hau Accessories, have gained a reputation for high quality in products and service in over ten years of working with the best names in the business. Their handlebars, stems, seatposts and specialty BMX parts appear on many of the better models from manufacturers such as Mongoose, Trek, Schwinn, Sunn, GT, Diamondback, Redline, Huffy, SE, Hoffman Bikes, Haro, KHE, Free Agent, Specialized, DK and more. They develop and manufacture parts for brands including O’Neal, Profile, Odyssey, Primo, Sun-Ringle, DK and others. If you see something in the Pazzaz range that looks familiar, it’s probably because they make the part you know by some other name.
> **bmxultra.com:** Who are Pazzaz?
> Pazzaz: Well, Pazzaz is a brand we started about 3 years ago. We decided we should have a channel to market by which was independant of our established channels and by which we could develop our own ideas rather than only those of our existing cutomer base, meaning private label and OEM customers. Pazzaz is mid to high end, we develop and produce parts for road and mtb, as well as bmx.
> [bmxultra.com](https://bmxultra.com/interview/pazzaz/)